# Mistake in while loop? bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm screenlog.0
screen -X stuff 'X21'$(printf \\r)
while :
do
grep -i "T" $screenlog.0
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
FILE=/etc/passwd 
VAR=`head -n 1 $FILE` 
echo $VAR
rm screenlog.0
break
done
```

This script is to delete the file "screenlog.0" send a command (X21) to an screen interface.
Thats the first part and it works.

The second Part is the Problem:
That should test the content of "screenlog.0", is there an something with a "T" inside save the contant into a variable.

The error:

```
line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 11: `done'
```

To the "screen": Its an screen of an usb device that recive radio messages like this:

```
T350B00A66E2
H34D04DE4254
```

The script have to scan for the incomming messages with "T" at the beginning (The first letter is a Type field behind this a hex code.

Some ideas to correct or other solutions?

I corrected my code a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
>screenlog.0
screen -X stuff 'X21'$(printf \\r)
while :
do
sleep 2
grep -i "T" $screenlog.0
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
screenlog.0=/etc/passwd
VAR=`head -n 1 $screenlog.0`
echo $VAR
break
fi
done
```

The new error is:

```
grep: .0: No such file or directory
```

All 5 seconds....

The file screenlog.0 exist .. :(

Comment: Note that you can test the exit status of the `grep` command directly: `if grep -i "T" screenlog.0`.  You also probably don't want the `$` in front of `$screenlog.0` given that the script otherwise manipulates `screenlog.0` with no `$`.  It's also better to use the `$(…)` notation rather than use the back-ticks notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh...you missed `fi` in your script :). Like syntax as follows `if [ condition ];then #dosomething fi`

For your script

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    FILE=/etc/passwd  
    VAR=`head -n 1 $FILE` 
    echo $VAR
    rm screenlog.0
    break
fi
```

Comment: @DemonDragon change from `$screenlog.0` to `"screenlog.0"`.Also note you removed on startup `rm screenlog.0`. remove that line.